# Microsoft.Graph.GraphServiceClient how to limit properties returned?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-sdks, azure-ad-b2c

I am using Azure AD B2C. I was hoping to get a count of the number of users - however, according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/microsoft-graph-operations):

> Azure AD B2C currently does not support advanced query capabilities on
> directory objects. This means that there is no support for $count ...

Great, so I thought the next best thing to do was to perform a query to get all the ids of the users, i.e.:

```
var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
    {
       AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
    };

var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential( tenant_id, client_id, client_secret, options );

var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

var users = await graphClient.Users
                  .Request()
                  .Select( "id" )
                  .GetAsync();

// This shows other properties returned in addition to "id" ...

if ( users is not null )
{
   Console.WriteLine( JsonSerializer.Serialize( users ) );
}
```

I was under the impression (from the documentation) that using .Select( "id" ) would only return the "id" property, instead, the graph client returns what I assume are a default set  of properties per user in addition to the "id", i.e.:

```
[
{"accountEnabled":null,
 "ageGroup":null, 
 ...more properties...,
 "id":"xxxx...",
 "@odata.type":"microsoft.graph.user"
}, 
{"accountEnabled":null,
 "ageGroup":null, 
 ... more properties ...,
 "id":"xxxx...",
 "@odata.type":"microsoft.graph.user"
}, ...
]
```

I am probably doing something wrong, but just how do you return ONLY the property (in this case "id") WITHOUT any other properties?  I have yet to find an example or documentation that describes how to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: just like what you found, `Azure AD B2C currently does not support advanced query capabilities`, and `Select` is advanced query as well. so....

Comment: When you use `.Select( "id" )` the graph client will request the graph server to return only value for `id` property of all users in the response. The response will be deserialized to `User` model and only `User.Id` will be filled. Other properties on `User` object will have default value based on their type.

Comment: @TinyWang - Is there a list of ALL "advanced query capabilities" available in one location?  If I understand correctly, trying to get a single property from the Graph when using B2C is not possible - because the API will always return a default set of properties in addition to those Select()ed.

Comment: Found list of advanced query capabilies at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/aad-advanced-queries?tabs=csharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @user2250152 and @Rukmini - the "answer" per se is that the graph QUERY returns only the selected / requested properties, that is, when the following code is used:

```
var users = await graphClient.Users
           .Request()
           .Select("id")
           .GetAsync();
```

The QUERY returns the "ids" as illustrated in @Rukmini's answer, but then the graphClient populates a list of "User" objects that is returned when the call completes.  The User objects will contain the Id property as well as all the other properties associated with a User object as mentioned by @user2250152.

Thanks again for clearing this up.

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results successfully like below:***

To get the **Azure AD b2c User IDs** I used the below code:

```cs
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Azure.Identity;

var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
var tenantId = "b2corg.onmicrosoft.com";
var clientId = "ClientID";

var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
{
    AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
};

var userName = "admin@b2corg.onmicrosoft.com";
var password = "password";

var userNamePasswordCredential = new UsernamePasswordCredential(
    userName, password, tenantId, clientId, options);

var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(userNamePasswordCredential, scopes);
var users = await graphClient.Users
           .Request()
           .Select("id")
           .GetAsync();

users.ToList().ForEach(x => { Console.WriteLine("\nid: " + x.Id); });
```

[image]

I also tried in the Microsoft Graph Explorer, and I am able to fetch only the User IDs like below:

```json
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=id
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks - if you use: Console.WriteLine( JsonSerializer.Serialize( users ) ); -- do you see additional properties in addition to "id"? (See my updated code example)

Comment: When I use  Console.WriteLine( JsonSerializer.Serialize( users ) ) I can see all the additional properties with id too.

Comment: Yes - Thank-you - I was under the impression the GraphServiceClient would only return an object with the requested properties ("id" in this case), instead, it seems to be returning the "id" AND additional properties - which is where I was confused.  As you stated in your  other comment - "Other properties on User object will have default value based on their type".  So the graph QUERY returns only the "id", but the GraphServiceClient returns User objects with other properties.